# The in-review-queues edit layout is different from the normal (out-of-review-queues) edit layout on mobile. How can I always use the former?

Tags: discussion, review, edits

I can't always be in front of a computer, so I sometimes use an Android/Apple phone (with Brave browser) to use [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). There I have noticed that when I edit a post in the review queues by clicking on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button below it, I get an interface like this (cropped screenshot):

[image: mobile interface when pressing the "Edit" button in the review queues]

However, when I edit a post out of a review queue, I get an interface like this one (cropped screenshot):

[image: mobile interface by pressing the "Edit" button out of the review queues]

I prefer the first interface, the in-review queues one, but I'm not able to use it unless or until I edit in a review queue.

Responsiveness is enabled (But I am not sure, but the responsiveness button shows the option "disable responsiveness", so it seems like responsiveness is enabled) and the desktop mode is not on in both cases.

How can I always get the first edit interface when I'm editing on my mobile?

Comment: Yeah the mobile editing interface is hard to use. I used to edit a lot on mobile. Apparently I like pain. These days I only use SE on a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue *exactly* (it looks like the desktop website is on in your second screenshot), but I indeed get two different interfaces when trying to edit posts in and out of a review queue when I am on my phone using the ***mobile*** version of the site.

- This is the edit layout I get in a review queue (same as yours):

  [image: edit layout in a review queue]
- And this is the (quite spartan) layout I get outside a review queue:

  [image: edit layout outside a review queue]

The ***mobile*** version of Ask Ubuntu (actually all SE websites) is quite limited and provides a relatively bad experience almost in everything except basic navigation of posts. That's why SE tries to improve the mobile experience and make it on par with the desktop one. So the *mobile* version of the SE websites [will soon be deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views).

Thus the solution to your issue could be the use of the new, fully responsive layout. To enable it, scroll to the bottom of the Ask Ubuntu website in your mobile and select the ***full site*** option (see screenshot below).

[image: change to "full site" layout]

With the ***full site*** option enabled, the edit layout is the same (at least in my case) for posts both in and out of a review queue and similar to the following:

[image: edit layout with the "full site" option enabled]

Comment: No, It is not same in my case, I have full site
 enabled

Comment: If I click on edit I get the same interface as shown in question

Comment: Which browser do you use ?

Comment: I'm using Firefox, but it's the same for Chrome too. Are you sure you have responsiveness enabled?

Comment: yes, I get the option "disable responsiveness"

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Does the reputation (2K) play a role in having different UIs for editing?

Comment: @RandomPerson Well, you could tell us. Do you see what someone sees?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog All the review queues are empty now. But, I can confirm that edit UI in non-review queue pages looks like what *someone* is seeing https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFMch.png. So, perhaps this is a bug which needs to be reported in MSE.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog [Here is what it looks like for me](https://imgur.com/a/MmjFkqt) (a less than 2k user), as per [your request in Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59878740#59878740)

Comment: @cocomac Did you use *full site* or *mobile view*? I was using *full site*.

Comment: @cocomac You are using the mobile editing interface. We are talking about the full site UI.

Comment: In-review queues are full site by default! So you are seeing what I see. But in the normal editing UI, you are using the Mobile UI which is good for nothing! Can you tell me what kind of interface do you get, when you click on "full site" while editing?

Comment: You have an above 2k reputation @BeastOfCaerbannog So, you won't get the interface as I do, You get the interface known as inline editing.